# C++ multiple inheritance, confused with addresses of base classes in derived object

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why does code below print `01`?
I expected `00`. Why does operator== return true in first case if addresses aren't equal?

```
#include <iostream>

class B1
{
    int m_i;
};

class B2
{
    double m_d;
};

class D
    : public B1
    , public B2
{
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    B2 *b2 = &d;

    std::cout << "d:\t" << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&d) << "\t" << &d << "\n";
    std::cout << "b2:\t" << reinterpret_cast<void*>(b2) << "\t" << b2 << "\n";


    std::cout << (reinterpret_cast<void*>(b2) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(&d));
    std::cout << (b2 == &d);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives output:

```
d:  0xbfd65fa4  0xbfd65fa4
b2: 0xbfd65fa8  0xbfd65fa8

01
```

Comment: (reinterpret_cast<void*>(b2)==(&d)reinterpret_cast<B2*>(&d));         try this.

Comment: std::cout << "(B2*)&d\t" << static_cast<B2*>(&d) << "\t" << &d << "\n";
is the key.

Comment: BTW you don't need `reinterpret_cast` to cast to `void*`; `static_cast` is sufficient.

Comment: This is an interesting question regarding implicit conversion. However, is it not a symptom that something is wrong if you want to cast a base class pointer to a derived type? Sounds dangerous to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compare `b2` and `&d` without casting to void, the compiler is implicitly casting them to a common datatype - in this case, `d` is being implicitly casted to its `B2` base class.

When you compare by casting to void, you get the true underlying address of the object, and since `D` inherits from `B1` before `B2` this is the address of its `B1` base class.